# How to set plain text content to tinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have this string:

```
let s = `
> line1
> line2
> line3
> line4
> — View it on GitLab. You're receiving this e.....
`
```

And I need to set it in tinyMCE when the user clicks a button, so I have this code:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(s);
```

The problem is that I get in the editor:

```
> line1> line2> line3> line4> — View it on GitLab. You're receiving this e.....
```

How can I preserve my plain text new lines?

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE is an HTML editor so whitespace in a string is not maintained.

If you want "newlines" you need to convert them to appropriate HTML (`<p>` or `<br>`) before you load them into TinyMCE.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose each line in `<p>` like this:

```
s = s.split(">");
var len = s.length;
var new_str = "";
for (i=1;i<len;i++)
    new_str += "<p> >" + s[i] + "</p>";           
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(new_str);
```

Look at this [Demo](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Fnfaab/13) I created. Just click on `mybutton`